# "transform.position" is being calculated from a single instance of a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, I have a projector looking thing as a prefab. It has script that calculates the distance between it and player object along with several other things(raycast and angle), and if it is below it's range then it executes some code inside. Now when I was experimenting with several projectors in scene I noticed that ALL of them calculate their range to player from the first placed instance of projector. Not really sure why this is happening, but I guess I have to add some "thisObject" kind of line somewhere.

Here is the code of that calculation:

```
    private GameObject player;
    

    private Transform target;    

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        target = player.transform;
        lt = GetComponent<Light>();
    }
...
    public void scan()
    {
        playerVelocityRate = target.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().playerVelocity.magnitude;
        
        float finalRate = Time.deltaTime * rate;

        if (Vector2.Distance(target.position, transform.position) <= range && RaycastCheck.playerCasted){

        // do something
        }
    }
```

scan() is called from Spotlight.cs script like so:

```
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !GetComponent<EnableSpotlight>().isEnabling && (target.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude <= disableRange){
            GetComponent<DisableSpotlight>().disable(downTime, fixTime);
        }
        if(rotates) GetComponentInParent<ScanBackandForth>().rotate();
        GetComponent<SpotlightDetection>().scan();
    }
```

Comment: Sounds unlikely and hard to tell with the code you provided .. there is no "thisObject" kind of line .. `transform.position` clearly uses **this instance**'s `Transform` component .. while `player` would probably be the same for all instances. How is `scan` called?

Comment: Edited into the question

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It really is quite a dumb mistake, but in case someone has similar issue and wanders in here, here's what was wrong:

There were two elements in my if statement that caused the error:

1. I used `Vector2.Distance()` to calculate the distance between two objects, but there were some errors in calculations, because clearly if statement was true even when the distance was bigger than range. However, when I changed it to `(target.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude` it worked just fine.
2. I accidentally made my raycast check boolean static, which made so that only first object's raycast boolean is checked. Removed the static part and now it works fine.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. However, in the question there is not enough detail to actually reproduce the issue and it is very questionable if this will be helpful for anyone else in the future ;)